# What is the confidence of the solution to a system of linear equations with associated correlation coefficients?

Tags: regression

I am writing a high school statistics question that requires students to **calculate the reliability of a solution to a system of linear equations** by first creating lines of best fit using two data sets. Here is the data:

Data Set 1:

x values: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}

y values: {8,9,5,9,6,7,2,4,3,5,1,3,2,6,1,5}

Line of best fit: y=-.36x+7.8

Correlation coefficient of data set 1: -.65

Data Set 2:

x values: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

y_values: {2,1,6,2,4,3,8,6,5,1,8,7,5,7,9,3}

Line of best fit: y=.27x+2.6

Correlation coefficient of data set 2: .48

The solution to the system of linear equations formed by y=-.36x+7.8 and y=.27x+2.6 is (8.3,4.8).

The data sets are both plotted on this graph: [image: Hand-Drawn Scatter Plot]

**Question: Given the scatter plots show relatively weak correlations, the solution to our system of linear equations is not 100% guaranteed. How do I calculate the [error margin/reliability/confidence] of this solution (8.3,4.8)? The goal for my students is to understand how changes in the correlation coefficients of their observational data upon which they derive their lines of best fit can lower the accuracy of the solution to the system.**

Thank you!